Summoning Emoji menu for Google Voice: MacOS Safari
Context: MacOS Ventura: Intel CPU. => Safari pointed to Google Voice for sending text messages.
Question: The Google Voice iPhone app's keyboard has a key to provide access to emojis.  Is there a similar key or method to select emoji's from said context? Maybe there is a work-around?
Reddit indicates that in Windows,  the combination of Winkey+Period will summon the emoji menu.  How would one send the equivalent sequence in MacOS via keyboard?  Maybe this only works in Windows...
https://www.reddit.com/r/Googlevoice/comments/agqicc/emoji_keyboard_shortcut/

When using MacOS:
Control + Command + Space 

will summon Apple's emoji keyboard for any application including OP's context.
